# MongoDB .ns and .0 files

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mean-stack, nosql

I have one .ns file and one .0 file. How do I run and import these files in my mongodb localhost and run it to view its data ? I am using MongoDB version 3.4.0 . Please help in this

Answer (score 0):

go to your cmd and type this

*path/of/your/mongodb/mongod*

then open another cmd

*path/of/your/mongodb/mongo*

then hit enter

then now open your collection :)

Please refer to this when you need help to show your collection [in here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/)